How could I get the transform matrix from rotate and position
I want to know how to get transform matrix form rotate and position matrix
I have a gaussian splatting training data (cameras.json):
{
    "id": 0, 
    "img_name": "_DSC9040", 
    "width": 5025, 
    "height": 3312, 
    "position": [-0.044550560003616964, 1.4236172811064225, 2.92660596573917], 
    "rotation": [
        [-0.9982609640488053, -0.010911420501731176, 0.057930894684822855], 
        [-0.023242959401519592, 0.9759623621223222, -0.2166961756904737], 
        [-0.054173909722383416, -0.21766581868371465, -0.974518742191313]
    ], 
    "fy": 4285.457130435278, 
    "fx": 4328.590804346088
}

I try to define:
transform_matrix = [[-0.9982609640488053, -0.010911420501731176, 0.057930894684822855, -0.044550560003616964], 
[-0.023242959401519592, 0.9759623621223222, -0.2166961756904737, 1.4236172811064225], 
[-0.054173909722383416, -0.21766581868371465, -0.974518742191313,  2.92660596573917],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]))

but it seems wrong.

The transform matrix is composed of a rotation matrix R ("rotation" in your json) and a translation vector t ("position" in your json). When you stack them together, as you did, in an [R | t] 4x3 matrix with the additional fourth row [0,0,0,1] you get your 4x4 transform matrix (let's denote it by T). When this matrix is multiplied by a homogeneous vector h = [x, y, z, 1].T, the result is a homogeneous vector h' = [x', y', z', 1].T corresponding to performing the non-homogeneous operation [x', y', z'].T = R*[x, y, z].T + t.
Now, usually there are two possible meanings to this transform. It can either be:
(1) The transformation of a vector h in camera coordinates to a vector h' in world coordinates.
(2) The inverse transformation of a vector h in world coordinates to a vecotr h' in camera coordinates.
This can be confusing so some texts (and code) actually write explicitly T_c2w or T_w2c (corresponding to 1 and 2 above).
Anyway, from the naming "position" of your t-vector, I suspect it is the position of the camera in the world. This means that your transform probably corresponds to option (1) above. Why? A simple rule of thumb test is to see the effect of applying the transform on the origin vector [0, 0, 0, 1].T (i.e., multiplying it by the transform matrix). This reconstructs the "position" vector, so if "position" indeed means the camera position in the world, then you took the origin of the camera in camera coordinates and transformed it to world coordinates (hence (1)).
I suspect that what you're interested in is (2). In order to get the transform matrix corresponding to (2) from your matrix T, you can just invert it (e.g., using python's numpy.linalg.inv(T)) or use the explicit formula
T_inv = [[R.T | -R.T*t], [0,0,0,1]]
(see for example here for this formula).
